# Django: How to hide trailing zeros of DecimalField across the framework

Tags: python, django

I needed to have numbers that are not integers but also have halves `0.5` so I switched my model from `IntegerField` to `DecimalField`.

However, numbers now show as `5.00` which is way too burdening. What are my options to display the numbers without trailing zeros: `0.5` instead of `0.50`and `5` instead of `5.00`?

**I am interested to know how to structure the framework to make that work - functions, decorators, or some kind of template tags or maybe some kind of localization. Someone that knows better should be able to dissect and explain the best choices.**

Comment: My model is `decimal_places=2` so `0.333333` i am guessing will be just `0.33`. The other `1001.2` but that's edge case, I don't care so much about it.

Comment: so wait ... do you want halves(ie only 0.5 increments?) ? or do you want hundredths max with zeros chopped off? (ie 0.1 is fine(for 0.10) so is 0.11(for 0.1111)

Comment: I am interested in the logistics in implementing a number formatting, rather than going into details on decimal points. I edited the question to be clearer

Comment: One other thing you could try is, if it's only halves, you could multiply all values by a factor of 10 prior to inserting in the database and divide by a factor of 10 when pulling them out. It can be a little confusing though. If it's dollars, one way to think about it would be as "cents" instead. For instance $0.5 == 50 cents.

Answer (score 4):

To do this in templates, the simplest way is to use the [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) built-in filter. To do this in code, you have more options - you can either write your own formatting code or import `floatformat` from `django.template.defaultfilters` and call it on the decimal value.

In general, `DecimalField` is a fine choice for this kind of thing, but you shouldn't declare it as more precise than you need.

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly, I could either use `floatformat` or write my own filter. and then in the code I would do `{{points|myfilter}}`?

Comment: You could write your own filter either way, come to think of it, but registering one is very marginally more complex than just writing a custom formatting function that you can call from within Python. The `{{points|myfilter}}` syntax is only for templates. In Python code you'd want something like `floatformat(points)`.